# Playing WMV files and Asx files

Tags: application-development, multimedia, pygtk

I have a question about this page:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/all/diy-media-player-with-pygtk/

My question is about setting supported video and audio types? Do I have to have the codec installed on my computer in order for it to play? I want to set it to play wmv files. How do I do this? How do I download and install the codec onto my Ubuntu from the terminal?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We try to keep to one question per post here so as to avoid problems with split posts and make it easier for others to find relevant questions. Can you please repost your inquiry about tar.bz2 extension files as a separate question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the Restricted Extras ? If not, go here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats For tar.bz2, there may be many ways and different types of applications you can install not-compiled packages, but you can follow this:

```
1. Untar the package
2. tar xf <file>.tar
3. cd /<file>
4. ./configure
```

Comment: why not just: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras ?